# Circle chart in SCSS

Tags: html, css, math, sass, frontend

I am trying to make 3 circle charts using scss and html

I have Posted the actual scss and html in the JS Fiddle but for you to preview there is a compiled version below.

The problem is when the value radius of the middle chart (.circle2) is 50 it works fine, but when 40 at start of animation a wierd trailing animation starts any idea why? Rather a math problem I guess.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqpka861/)

```css
.body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#svg .circle {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: coral;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 113.09734 188.49556;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 188.49556;
  }
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 188.49556;
  }
}

#svg .circle2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b530c9;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 157.07963 314.15927;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 314.15927;
  }
}

#svg .circle3 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #59e629;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 62.83185 251.32741;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 251.32741;
  }
}
/* This is the css compiled version of the scss*/

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circle Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <svg id="svg" height="100" width="100">
    <circle class="circle" cx = "50" cy = "50" r="30"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg" height="200" width="200">
    <circle class="circle2" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg" height="200" width="200">
    <circle class="circle3" cx="100" cy="100" r="40" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray. Seems that your dash-array property might be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second `$circumference` parameter in `stroke-dasharray` is not high enough for some reason. Your math seems sound but when I increase the circumference two fold in both 0% keyframe and target it seems to no longer give the bug.

This solution is possible because the second parameter of `stroke-dasharray` provides the amount of empty space there should be and it is no problem to have this overflow.

I couldn't confirm but I think that the problem is that this second parameter is also animated, changing the value below the desired value at some point.

[Reply JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8r42fbv/27/)

```css
.body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#svg .circle {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: coral;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 113.09734 377;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 376;
  }
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 376;
  }
}

#svg .circle2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b530c9;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 157.07963 628;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 628;
  }
}

#svg .circle3 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #59e629;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 62.83185 502;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: circleinchart 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes circleinchart {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 502;
  }
}
/* This is the css compiled version of the scss*/

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circle Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <svg id="svg" height="100" width="100">
    <circle class="circle" cx = "50" cy = "50" r="30"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg" height="200" width="200">
    <circle class="circle2" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg" height="200" width="200">
    <circle class="circle3" cx="100" cy="100" r="40" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems that if you manually set the first keyframe to a value that is low, you get the same effect, suggesting that the second parameter is somehow animated from a value below $circumference